# Помогите с ошибкой новичку в Python/Питон

Tags: python

Сейчас изучаю множества. Снизу прикреплен проблемный отрывок. Почему-то когда я объединяю множества после строки if, полученное объединение не определяется("is not defined").

```
team1={'Илья', 'Некит', 'Влад'}
team2={'Артём', 'Санёк'}
if (((input('Желаете объединить команды? ')).upper) == 'ДА'):
    union = team1.union(team2)
print(', '.join(union))

NameError: name 'union' is not defined
```

Причём когда я пишу без строки с if, всё получается:

```
team1={'Илья', 'Некит', 'Влад'}
team2={'Артём', 'Санёк'}
union = team1.union(team2)
print(', '.join(union))

Итог: Илья, Некит, Влад, Артём, Санёк.
```

Вопрос: почему не получается вариант кода с использованием if? Как это можно решить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во первых, надо добавить скобки к `upper`-у. Во вторых, у Вас много лишних скобок.
Работающий и правильный код выглядит так:

```
team1={'Илья', 'Некит', 'Влад'}
team2={'Артём', 'Санёк'}
if input('Желаете объединить команды? ').upper() == 'ДА':
    union = team1.union(team2)
try:
    print(', '.join(union))
except NameError:
    print('Команды не объединены.')
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы забыли скобки после `upper`, вы не выполняете функцию.